# clob datatype is causing performace issue

Tags: oracle, spring-mvc, plsql

UPDATED: The code is working as expected but the performance is very slow. When I do a search without including CLOB data then the query runs very fast but if I include CLOB variable in my search the query is very slow. I am using CLOB to pass large string data('aaaaaaa,bbbb,c,ddddd...') and store those data in global table for better performance, I thought doing such will maximize query performance. How can I improve/utilize my CLOB variable for better perfomance? Please look at the code below for more information. Appreciated for any help.  I am still struggling with performance can anyone help/provide any suggestions please.

```
GLOBAL TT GlobalTemp_EMP( //this already exists
emp_refno (30 byte);
)


Create or replace PROCEDURE Employee(

emp_refno IN CLOB

)

AS

Begin
OPEN p_resultset FOR
with inputs ( str ) as (  //red error line here 
       select to_clob(emp_refno )
       from dual
     ),
     prep ( s, n, token, st_pos, end_pos ) as (
       select ',' || str || ',', -1, null, null, 1
         from inputs
       union all
       select s, n+1, substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
              end_pos + 1, instr(s, ',', 1, n+3)
         from prep
         where end_pos != 0
     )
INSERT into GlobalTemp_EMP   //red error line here 
select token from prep;


select e.empname, e.empaddress, f.department
from employee e
join department f on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
and e.emp_refno  in (SELECT emp_refno from GlobalTemp_EMP) //using GTT In subquery
```

Comment: add punctuation marks to your text. i do not see a question here.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко I did , have a look at it. How to insert comma seperated clob string to GTT

Comment: what a nice person of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
put this code between BEGIN and OPEN p_resultset FOR : this might have some performance issue though.
INSERT into GlobalTemp_EMP 
with inputs ( str ) as (  
       select to_clob(emp_refno )
       from dual
     ),
     prep ( s, n, token, st_pos, end_pos ) as (
       select ',' || str || ',', -1, null, null, 1
         from inputs
       union all
       select s, n+1, substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
              end_pos + 1, instr(s, ',', 1, n+3)
         from prep
         where end_pos != 0
     )
  
select token from prep where token is not NULL;
```

Comment: yup thank you very much its working as expected but I noticed now the query is taking longer than before to get the results from proc....any suggestions to increase the performance

Comment: well don't know much about  performnace, I am pretty sure somebody will help you on this issue...good luck mate!

Answer (score 0):

The below doesn't seem to be valid syntax:

```
GLOBAL TT GlobalTemp_EMP( //this already exists
emp_refno (30 byte);
)
```

I don't know the reason for using byte semantics, or whether you defined it as a clob or char or varchar2.

If it is currently a clob, then perhaps you could define the column as `emp_refno varchar2(30 char)` and add a unique index, changing the `Employee` procedure to only insert new IDs. An index would help the insertions more than when you read it out.

If you want to insert a huge amount of data into `GlobalTemp_EMP` faster, I would recommend making it a regular table, pre-processing the data (such as in Perl or other language) to split IDs *outside* Oracle and then use SQL*Loader. Or perhaps an external table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a global temporary table will improve your performance at all (at least without indexes). Are you sure these are `CLOBs`? At a glance, these seem to be varchars.

To compare `CLOBs`, you should be using dbms_lob.compare. I think `=` will do an implicit conversion to a varchar (and truncate), then do the comparison.

Comment: at first I was using emp_refno as varchar2 but If passing large data varchar2 might not be enough so I passed  emp_refno as CLOB. GTT contains a single column there is no indexes. I am really stuck here any guidance/suggestion will be appreciated. any better way to achieve this?

Comment: How big is your comma separated string? It's not clear where it's coming from; does it really have to be a comma separated string? And how bad is your performance, is this taking 2 seconds when you want 50 ms or is it taking 30 min?

Comment: client uploads text file with ID in each line(102,103--), I am parsing these ID as comma seperated string in controller and sending them to procedure to insert into GTT. The tex file can contain thounsands of ID'S, I tried with 10K id and it took me a little more than a min to process the result. I am sending as a CLOB as text file ID's might exceed 4000 bytes. It dosent have to be a comma separated string if there any others options - I just don't know how to implement in any other ways